# Clarification about Converting Appengine Backends to Modules

Tags: java, google-app-engine, app-engine-modules, gae-module

i got a basic doubt about `backends`, since `backends` are deprecated, *google is recommending us to move to modules*, however,

Previously backends and frontends can run on same project (same code), whereas modules needs seperate application for each module we define. So

**Q: is it possible to have backend modules run on same code, or have to create seperate application for it ?**

creating seperate application just for backends usage doesn't seems to be good idea.

Am i wrong on something ? please clarify me!

Thanks!

Comment: What makes you think you need a separate application?

Comment: am asking that only, since each module we define need a war folder , so  it will have seperate src folders too right, is it possible to access java files in only war folder to the other ?